# libgdx sharedPreferences

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I have been struggling with this for too long.
Can some one take a look at my code and tell why I cannot find the saved file.

```
  public static void save(){

    try{
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.local("data/testscore.xml");

        fileHandle.writeString("Test", false);


        Gdx.app.log("Settings", "saved  "  );

        boolean exists = Gdx.files.internal("testscore.xml").exists();
        Gdx.app.log("Settings", "loaded  " + exists);

    }catch(Throwable e){
        Gdx.app.log("Settings", "not saved  " + e);
    }
}
```

My Log Cat

```
  04-04 17:31:18.863: I/Settings(14274): saved  
  04-04 17:31:18.873: I/Settings(14274): loaded  false
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```
  boolean exists = Gdx.files.local("data/testscore.xml").exists();
```

Comment: Reasons not to retype the same string multiple places throughout your code. Make that a constant somewhere.